# I can not acces excel (.xlsx) file neither from assets folder via AssetManager nor Internal storage via getFileExternalStorage() method

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-development

I can not acces excel (.xlsx) file neither from assets folder via AssetManager nor Internal storage via getFileExternalStorage() method, it display a permissions issue

But without success, Any help would be appreciated !

I added the 2 lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried even adding methods to ask for permissions at Run Time because I use more than 23 in API version

Comment: You have two problems. One for assets resource for which you dont need any permission. And one for file storage. Please dont mix them. Make two posts. One for each. For both post the code too.

Comment: And there is no such thing as getFileExternalStorage().